# AWS Appsync - setting limit on rows returned from a list query

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, ampl

I want to increase the number of rows returned greater than the default 10. Using the limit parameter does not seem to work.

I have tried passing the limit in several different ways but I always receive only the default 10 rows returned. There should be 12 rows returned which match the filter criteria.

```
  const filter = {
    or: [
      { firstname: { contains: searchValue } },
      { lastname: { contains: searchValue } },
      { emailaddress: { contains: searchValue } },
      { phone: { contains: searchValue } }
    ]

  };

  const limit = {limit: 50};
  // const limit = 50; // this does not work either

  const result = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(listProviders, {filter}, {limit})
  );
```

I expect to receive true number of rows which match the filter criteria. Only receive 10 rows back. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Attempting the same query via AWS Appsync returns the 12 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.

```
const result = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(listProviders, {filter}, {limit})
);
```

is the wrong syntax. `graphqlOperation` only takes two arguments: the query and some options. You want to put both keys onto that object.

```
const limit = 50;
const result = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(listProviders, {filter, limit})
);
```